# What's the model of the droids In Star Wars Episode 3 in Mustafar?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, droids

When Anakin arrives at Mustafar and walks in to meet Viceroy, 5 little droids enter before him. They are shown in the screenshot. The scene is around at 01:33:00 in the movie.

[image]

Do you know the model of these droids?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are the [MSE-4 droid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/MSE-4_droid), the predecessors of the MSE-6 used on the Deathstar by The Galactic Empire

Answer (score 12):

According to the [*New essential Guide to Droids*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_Essential_Guide_to_Droids) (a pre-Disney sourcebook), these are [MSE-4 Mouse Droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/MSE-series), used to detects and report leaks in the Mustafar lava shield.

> The uses for mouse droids are limited only by their owner's creativity. **On Mustafar, the operators of the lava mines used MSE-4s to scout for life support leaks.** Aboard the Death Star, MSE-6s guided stormtroopers through the maze-like corridors.